# Get name and version info of every ActiveX component registered on PC (.NET)

Tags: .net, activex

I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to get a list of all ActiveX components regeistered on a PC along with the version information.

Basically I need the long name of the component (ex:Microsoft Excel 12.0 object Library) , Filename (ex:EXCEL.EXE), and version number.

I want to get this programmatically using .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your Registry in HKCR\CLSID - there are all COM Components registered.

But: You will receive a lot of ActiveX Controls! I dont know what this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Not .Net, but Microsoft provides the source for OLEView

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9yyfff5(VS.80).aspx

I consider it the classic way of looking at the registered controls on your system.

I also agree with Arthur,  you will see a bunch of controls.